# Getting the Height of Navigation bar dynamically in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overlay

My website is based on React and react-strap. Well, I had my `.header-overlay` to cover the whole entire background in `.header`. But what is happening here is that because of the `.navbar`, the `.header-overlay` sticks out of `.header` vertically.

I figured that using `calc(100vh - heightOfNavigationBar)` would resolve this. 
But, I couldn't find any way to get the height of `.navbar` by dynamically. Is there any way to resolve this? (navbar is embedded in react-strap)

CSS CODE:

```
.navbar{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.header {
    background: url("../images/headerbg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50% fixed ;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

.header-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.4);
    height: 100vh;
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<header className="header">

        {/*Navigation Bar*/}
        <div>
             <NavBar/> <--from react-strap
        </div>


        <div className="header-overlay">
             SOME CODE HERE
        <div>
</header>
```

Comment: maybe you should also add your html code

Comment: Can't be done with pure CSS, as CSS is not able to analyze DOM. However I think it's unlikely you **really** need information about navbar height and it can be fixed with good application of CSS. Please share your HTML code.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I edited with HTML Code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `position: absolute` is an option, your solution would look something like this:

```css
.navbar{
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header {
    background: url("../images/headerbg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50% fixed ;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.header-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav class="navbar">
    Navbar
  </nav>
  <div class="header-overlay">
    This is the overlay
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP question. OP asked specifically to get navbar height dynamically.

Comment: Oh yay! This actually solved the problem! but Had to add z-index:1 to .navbar{}

Answer (score 5):

It Is Really Simple

Add "navbar" ID To Your Nav

Use JS To Set **Property Value**:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--nav-height', document.getElementById("navbar").offsetHeight);
```

Use Property In CSS:

*example:*

```
:root {
    --nav-height: 70px; /*You HAVE To Give A Default Fallback Value*/
}

.container-fs{
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - var(--nav-height));
}
```

HOW DOES IT WORK?

```
document.getElementById("navbar").offsetHeight
```

This Code Selects The Navbar Using The ID And Gets The Height Of The Nav

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty();
```

This Code Sets A CSS Property, *AKA* Variables, To The Height Of The Nav.

```
var(--nav-height)
```

This CSS Function Returns The Value Of The Property(Height Of The Navbar)

Comment: I am having a similar issue trying to get the navbar height dynamically. Could you write  a complete working code that shows all the code together. I can figure out where each parts go in the html page